# System.web.mail only accepts one attachment

Tags: c#, email, smtp, attachment, smtps

I'm trying to send an email with my application throug SMTPS, not supported by System.Net, but supported in System.Web.Mail.
If I send the mail with one attachment it works fine, but if the attachment are more than one I get an error of Invalid Attachment (when I call the new MailAttachment(filename), not when i add it to the message).
here is my code

```
        //attachments is a List<> of FileInfo()
        if (attachments != null)
        {
            List<MailAttachment> atts = new List<MailAttachment>();
            foreach (FileInfo attachment in attachments)
            {
                try
                {
                    atts.Add(new MailAttachment(attachment.FullName));
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    //error is in this try catch block, if attachments.Count > 1
                    string exc = ex.ToString();
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
                }
            }
            foreach(MailAttachment att in atts)
                pec.Attachments.Add(att);

        }
```

Comment: What is the value for `attachment.FullName` on the first and second iteration?

Comment: How about using [`System.Net.Mail`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of the old, [deprecated `System.Web.Mail`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mail(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: @Equalsk the complete path with the name of each file, I checked it, it loops right

Comment: @UweKeim because It does not support smtps on port 465

Comment: @Equalsk the fullname is something like: \\SERVER\Share\Folder\docs\filename.ext where filename is a `DateTime.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmssffff")` and ext could be any extension, for each file

Comment: I would guess that it has issues with that being a UNC path, probably because the permissions in one way or another are incorrect, maybe also it's picked up a file you didn't expect such as `Thumbs.db`. Purely as a test can you copy 3 of the files to your local machine and test the code with those? I would bet it works when the files are local. Have you got the exact true path of the one that causes the error?

Comment: The filenames are stored in a db and the files are created with my app, so a not expected file is improbable... I try with a local path and get back...

Comment: @Equalsk same error with a local path...

Comment: Don't know what to tell you. I copied/pasted your code verbatim and it works perfectly fine, only difference is my `attachments` object was a directory with several local file attachments in.

Comment: tryed to copy the files in a local dir before attaching them (programmatically) and then delete them, now it works...